# How to instrument async calls in NewRelic (.NET Agent)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, newrelic

I would like to make the `NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError` async. ([NoticeError documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/noticeerror-net-agent-api)).
There is no explicit async `NoticeError` function in the API.
But NewRelic says [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/other-features/async-support-net) that it is possible to "instrument" calls as async.
What does that mean? How do you accomplish this specifically on the `NoticeError` function?